# Coppersmith bivariate polynomial roots implementation

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, computational-number-theory, mathematical-software, software

Given $f(x,y)\in\mathbb Z[x,y]$ Coppersmith in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-68339-9_16 provides a provable method to find integer roots in polynomial time and this method was also studied in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24676-3_29 and https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11426639_15.

Have these methods been implemented in Python or Mathematica?

Sage has small_roots() but that is only for the univariate situation.

Answer (score 4):

An implementation in SageMath is available at https://github.com/ubuntor/coppersmith-algorithm

Comment: I saw that too. Not sure if it has been tested or just an amateur post.

Comment: Why not give it a try?